# fatal: 'git_url' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

When i run

```
G:\blogx>heroku create
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Creating name... done, stack is stack
web_url | git_url
```

on running

```
G:\blogx>git push heroku master
fatal: 'git_url' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
on running

```
 G:\blogx>git remote -v
    heroku  git_url (fetch)
    heroku  git_url (push)
```

I am not sure why this error is being generated...

Comment: Could you add the output of `git remote -v` to your question, please?

Comment: @AlexP Added git remote -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku wants you to deploy from [Git](http://git-scm.com/book), but you haven't got a valid URL to a git repository in your setup. Somehow, you've ended up with something called `git_url` instead of an actual path to git.

The easiest way to fix this is to run `git remote rm heroku` to remove the broken one, find your application's name in the Heroku control panel, then run [`heroku git:remote -a your-app-name-here`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote).

The [Heroku guide to deploying from Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) and the [Heroku getting started guides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart) is a useful reference.